# Write recursive algorithm with especified complexity

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I'm in a algorithm analysis course, and one exercise got me stuck because the complexity an what it asks for is too specific, this is the problem:

***Write a recursive algorithm that given a integer n as input, print Θ(n^log4 11(log n)) asterisks. To justify the complexity you can use the master theorem.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the second case of the master theorem.
As you know,

```
T(n) = aT(n/b)+f(n)
```

and if `f=Theta(n^log_{b}{a})` then `T(n) = Theta(n^log_{b}{a}*logn)

Hence, you need 11 recursion calls to 0.25 of the size of the input,
and in each call do a `n^log{4}{11}` "work"

So, a straight forward approach will be:

```
define f (n):
m = floor(log_{4}{11})
print ('*' * pow(n,m))
for i in (0,11):
   f(floor(n/4))
```